# Problem printing the contents of a text box in another textbox multiline

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tkinter

I am making a small app with Tkinter, for educational purposes, which consists of pressing a button and displaying the contents of a textobox ... in another multiline textbox.

The problem is that you see this:

```
<bound method Text.get of <tkinter.Text object.! Text2 >>
```

and not the content that I manually write of the textobox. The textbox that I would like to print in the multiline textobox (called text) is called textbox_test. Textbox_test is called

```
A = f "{test_textbox.get} {'' .join (word2)} {abitanti} abitanti su un'area di {superficie}".
```

Questo è il textobox

```
test_textbox = Text(window,width=10,height=1)
test_textbox.pack()
test_textbox.place(x=5, y=100)
```

How can I remove the error above and correctly display the text of a textbox? I attach complete code. Thank you

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import sqlite3
import random

window=Tk()
window.title("xxxxxxxx")
window.geometry("750x750")
window.configure(bg='#78c030')

con = sqlite3.connect('/home/xxxxxxxxxxx/Database.db')
cursor = con.cursor()

# Search Data
def city(name_city):
    name_city = city.get()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Info WHERE City =?',(name_city,))
    results = cursor.fetchone()
    return results


# Print Data in textbox multiline
def write():
    name_city = city.get
    results = city(name_city)
    inhabitants = results[2]
    surface = results[3]

    if categoria.get() == "Test 1" and sottocategoria.get() == "Test 1.1":

        cursor.execute('SELECT xxxxxxxx FROM TableExample ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1')
        word2 = cursor.fetchone()
        text.delete(1.0,END)
        
        A= f"{test_textbox.get} {''.join(word2)} {inhabitants} inhabitants on an area of {surface}"
        B= f"Che sale a"
        
        text.insert(tk.END, random.choice([A, B]))

   

button2 = Button(window, text="Button2", bg='white', command = write)
button2.pack()
button2.place(x=5, y=330)



### TEXTBOX MULTILINE ###
text = Text(window,width=63,height=38)
text.pack()
text.place(x=180, y=24)

### TEXTBOX ### 
test_textbox = Text(window,width=10,height=1)
test_textbox.pack()
test_textbox.place(x=5, y=100)


### CATEGORIA E SOTTO CATEGORIA ###
cat=StringVar()
sub_cat=StringVar()

def change_val(*args):
    if cat.get() == "Test 1":
        sottocategorias = ["Test 1.1", "Test 1.2", "Test 1.3"]
        sottocategoria.config(values=sottocategorias)
    else:
        sottocategorias = ["aaaa"]
        sottocategoria.config(values=sottocategorias)
    
categorias=["Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3"]
categoria=ttk.Combobox(window,value=categorias,textvariable=cat,width=16)
categoria.place(x=5, y=25)
cat.set("Scegliere categoria")

sottocategorias=["aaaa"]
sottocategoria=ttk.Combobox(window,textvariable=sub_cat,value=sottocategorias,
width=16)
sottocategoria.place(x=5, y=55)

cat.trace("w",change_val)


### COMBOBOX ###

def combo_nation():
    cursor.execute('SELECT DISTINCT Nation FROM Info')
    result=[row[0] for row in cursor]
    return result

def combo_city(event=None):
    val = city.get()
    cursor.execute('SELECT City FROM Info WHERE Nation = ?', (val,))
    result = [row[0] for row in cursor]
    city['value'] = result
    city.current(0)
    return result


nation=ttk.Combobox(window,state="readonly")
nation['value'] = combo_nation()
nation.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', combo_city)
nation.place(x=5, y=150,height = 25, width = 180)


city=ttk.Combobox(window,state="readonly")
city.place(x=5, y=180, height = 25, width = 180)


window.mainloop()
```

**IMPORTANT: If you try to change to A = f "{test_textbox.get (" 1.0 "," end-1c ")} {'' .join (word2)}, that's not good. The app won't open. Without this code instead opens**

Comment: It should be ```test_textbox.get('1.0',"end")```. You need to provide the parameters for getting a text from a ```Text``` widget

Comment: `test_textbox.get` is a function, `test_textbox.get()` calls the function.

Comment: @Sujay I tried, but it doesn't work. Maybe I'm wrong. Can you show me the code in the answer? What should I write? Thank you

Comment: @Bryan Oakley I tried, but it doesn't work. Maybe I'm wrong. Can you show me the code in the answer? What should I write? Thank you

Comment: `A = f "{test_textbox.get("1.0", "end-1c")} ...`

Comment: Why are you using to geometry managers: ```pack()``` and ```place()``` for one widget

Comment: @Bryan Oakley Thanks, but that's not good. The app does not open with your code. Do I have to correct the textobox in string and use "trace"? If so, can you show me how? I'm just starting out with Python. Thank you

Comment: @Sujay I am using tkinter. I am placing the objects in the graph form. Anyway can you help me to print <bound method Text.get of <tkinter.Text object.! Text2 >> which does not print the contents of the textbox? As I also told Bryan Oakley, do I need to convert the textobox to a string and use "trace"? Thank you

Comment: I tried to run code but there are few problems: first you fogot `()` in two `.get`, you use `squadra.get()` but `squadra` doesn't exist, You have two `city` - widget `city = ttk.Combobox(...)` and function `def city(...)` - and this can make problems. Other problem is that I don't have your database and not even query `CREATE ...` to create own database. So it is hard to test program to see all problems.

Comment: as for `<bound method Text.get of <tkinter.Text object.! Text2 >>` you already got solution. You have to use `A = f "{test_textbox.get("1.0", "end-1c")} ..." instead of `A = f "{test_textbox.get} ...". And if this gives new error then you have new problem and you would have to describe it new question on new page - or at least append to current question (not comment)

Comment: @furas You're right, it said squadra, because I modified the code specifically to post it here, so I simplified it for illustrative purposes. I forgot to change that word, but it's actually okay. So this is not a problem. False alarm. As for the database, everything works fine. The database is already created, you just need to read. As mentioned, the database works fine. I have tested it. All right. Another false alarm. The only problem that remains is <bound method etc. etc etc. I tried to change to A = f "{test_textbox.get (" 1.0 "," end-1c ")}, but the app won't open

Comment: it doesn't matter that you have created database - but I don't have created database so I can't run it.

Comment: @furas But I am saying that the database works perfectly. I have tested it. The only problem is to print the text from a textobox. I have to write the text manually with the keyboard: it does not depend on the database. So the database has nothing to do with it :)

Comment: do you get any error message when you run it in console after using `A = f "{test_textbox.get (" 1.0 "," end-1c ")}` ? And It wasn't full value but only part which you have to replace in full text. Full will be `A = f"{test_textbox.get('1.0','end-1c')} {''.join(word2)} {inhabitants} inhabitants on an area of {surface}"` And it need single `'  '` when it is put inside double `"  "`

Comment: BTW: you don't have to use `trace` - you can use `'<<ComboboxSelected>>'` to detect change.

Comment: @furas There is no error message in the console. 1.0 is highlighted in pink and the messagebox "invalid syntax" appears. I add '' ('1.0', 'end-1c') and now it works fine. All right. Thank you. A curiosity: why shouldn't I use Trace, but yes '<<ComboboxSelected>>'? Can you explain to me please? However you helped me: if you answer me as an answer, I accept your answer with the green sign :)

Comment: in previous comment you asked `do I need to ... use "trace"` and I said `you don't have to`. I didn't say `you shoudn't`. You can choose if you prefer `trace` or `'<<ComboboxSelected>>'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @BryanOakley said in comment you need `get` with `()` to run it and widget `Text` needs it with arguments like

```
A = f"{test_textbox.get('1.0','end-1c')} ...
```

It didn't work because it was only part which you would have to replace in full text, but it seems you replaced all text. Because you didn't run code in console so you couldn't see error message which could explain problem

Full line should be

```
A = f"{test_textbox.get('1.0','end-1c')} {''.join(word2)} {inhabitants} inhabitants on an area of {surface}"
```